# Docusign - Adding a non signing CC role with same routing order

Tags: docusignapi

We have one template configured in Docusign and have a requirement of adding one signer and one non-signer to whom we need to send a carbon copy,both,before and after the signing process.I chose the Add CC button and added the required role and specified the action as Receive a copy.Now, the email address for the signer and the non-signer are dynamic and hence I am using the API to populate the role name,email address. For the role name, I specify it in the template and use the same matching role name through code.

Now:

1) When I add the non-signer CC role with routing order as 2, everything works fine but the non-signer gets only a carbon copy of the completed email which I guess is correct since the routing order is 2. To enable the non signer to get the first email too,I kept the same routing order for both.

2) But when the routing order is the same,the non-signer gets a carbon copy but when the signer gets the email and opens the envelope for signing, the signer has to place either a signature/intial/company/title/date signed/text control to complete the signing process.In addition to this the editable fields become non-editable.

How can I get around this ?

Comment: I managed to solve this.For the same routing order,it looks like there is an internal string sort by role name.So if there is one signer and one non-signer cc role and the role names specified are 'Signer' and 'Carbon Copy' respectively then it works as mentioned in 2 above.When the role names are changed to 'Signer' and say 'XCarbon Copy',it works fine,the person with cc role gets the envelope before and after the signing process and the signer is able to sign the documents correctly.I am not sure if this is documented somewhere. Would be great if someone from docusign can confirm the same.

Answer (score 1):

@Ajay Iyengar, that is correct. The reason being is that  because the role names are the same, the two recipients are merged into one. By giving them a unique name, this behavior is no longer seen.

-Justin