# Why is my DocuSign CarbonCopy blank?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm attempting to send an envelope built from a template to one signer(Client) and have a carbon copy sent to our enroller.  I'm populating the tabs with information from my DB, specific to the signer, which is why I need to use the template.  I need the carbon copy to have the information present, or ideally to generate at the completed status.

When I set the routing order in the template as 1 for both the signer and CarbonCopy, the template is created and sent to the signer correctly, but the CC version is blank when sent.  However, if set the signer as 1 and CC as 2, the template still sends to signer correctly, but the CarbonCopy is never generated.  In neither case is the CarbonCopy sent on envelope completion.

I've tried renaming and moving the orders around as was suggested/answered in:
[Docusign - Adding a non signing CC role with same routing order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576980/docusign-adding-a-non-signing-cc-role-with-same-routing-order?answertab=oldest#tab-top), but hasn't solved my issue.

I've also attempted to use the recipients/signer/CarbonCopy tags instead of the TemplateRoles/TemplateRole tags, but I get an error message stating that TemplateID cannot be used with the recipient tags.

What can I change to either have the Carbon Copy not be blank or be recieved when the envelope is completed?

My code is as follows, with the text entries shortened for brevity:

```
 "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
     "<status>sent</status>" +
     "<emailSubject>DocuSign API - Signature Request from Template</emailSubject>" +
     "<templateId>" + templateId + "</templateId>" +
     "<templateRoles>" +
         "<templateRole>" +
             "<name>" + client.Name + "</name>" +
             "<email>" + client.Email + "</email>" + 
             "<roleName>" + "Signer" + "</roleName>" +
             "<tabs>" +
                 "<textTabs>" +
                     "<text>" +
                         "<tabLabel>Name</tabLabel>" +
                         "<value>" + client.name + "</value>" +
                         "<locked>true</locked>" +
                         "<documentId>1</documentId>" +
                         "<pageNumber>1</pageNumber>" +
                     "</text>" + 
                 "</textTabs>" +
             "</tabs>" +
         "</templateRole>" +
         "<templateRole>" +
             "<name>" + "enroller.Name" + "</name>" +
             "<email>" + enroller.Email + "</email>" + 
             "<roleName>" + "EnrollerCarbonCopy" + "</roleName>" +
         "</templateRole>" +
     "</templateRoles>" +
 "</envelopeDefinition>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Carbon Copy in DocuSign (CC) can view the envelope at any time, but receives the email based on the routing order. That recipient will also receive the final/completed document at the end of the process.

Example #1 - This example shows the Carbon Copy receiving the document only after Recipient 1 has signed

Recipient 1 set with Signing Order 1 - Needs to Sign

Recipient 2 set with Signing Order 2 - Carbon Copy

Recipient 3 set with Signing Order 3 - Needs to Sign

Example #2 - This example shows the Carbon Copy receiving the document after both Recipient 1 and 2 have signed

Recipient 1 set with Signing Order 1 - Needs to Sign

Recipient 2 set with Signing Order 2 - Needs to Sign

Recipient 3 set with Signing Order 3 - Carbon Copy

So if you want to send the document to a Recipient with all the eSignatures completed, add the carbon copy at the end of the workflow like example #2. In both examples the carbon copy only gets one email notification with an attached document.