# IS routing order for signers optional?

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I have 2 recipients and in my envelope, we do not want to force any specific  order for signing, so basically either of then can sign first. What routing order option should be set in such case? Can I omit the routing order for signers altogether?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to force any specific order for signing, then leave the routingOrder empty. The routingOrder will be set to the default value of 1.

Multiple signers can have the same routing order. See this [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/quick-tip-altering-recipients-and-routes/) for more information.

Comment: I was not specifying routing order to signers and cc recipients and it was working fine. The CC recipients were getting email from DocuSign only when the signers have completed which is the expected behavior as per the documentation. But if the CC recipients also are required to get the email before and after signing what is the best way to do this? Research pointed me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576980/docusign-adding-a-non-signing-cc-role-with-same-routing-order but this solution did not work for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post a new question so that a detailed answer can be provided.