# DocuSign signers and non-signers routing

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am currently not specifying any routing order for signers and non-signers(cc recipients). In this case non-signers get the email only when the signers have signed and completed the envelope. I need for non-signers to get email same time as signers (before signers sign) as well as after signers sign and complete. How to achieve this. I alresy looked at this solution [Docusign - Adding a non signing CC role with same routing order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576980/docusign-adding-a-non-signing-cc-role-with-same-routing-order)
But when I tried different roleNames and same routing order I get "errorCode": "ENVELOPE_HAS_DUPLICATE_RECIPIENTS",
How do we differtiate between signers and non-signers? I tried to use different role names, but did not work.
My request json:

```
{
    "status": "created",
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [{
            "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [],
                "initialHereTabs": [],
                "dateSignedTabs": []
            },
            "routingOrder": '1',
            "roleName": "Signer",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "name": "Signer Name",
            "email": "someone@somewhere1.com",
            "clientUserId": null
        }],
        "carbonCopies": [{
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "roleName": "CCRole",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "email": "someone1@somewhere.com"
        }, {
            "routingOrder": "2",
            "roleName": "CCRole",
            "recipientId": "2",
            "email": "someone2@somewhere.com"
        }]
    },
    "messagelock": "false",
    "emailsubject": "DocuSign:1xxxxx78-03 - Testcase",
    "emailblurb": "Please sign attached document(s)",
    "documents": [{
        "name": "11xxxxxx8-01- Documents",
        "documentid": "1",
        "documentBase64": null
    }],
    "customFields": {
        "textCustomFields": [{
            "value": "a54c00000000ogaAAA",
            "show": "false",
            "required": "true",
            "name": "DSFSSourceObjectId",
            "fieldId": null
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: `I am currently not specifying any routing order for signers and non-signers(cc recipients). In this case non-signers get the email only when the signers have signed and completed the envelope.` Thats an incorrect statement. Recipients at the same routing order will receive emails simultaneously when the envelope reaches the particular routing order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recipients at the same routing order will receive emails simultaneously when the envelope reaches the particular routing order. In addition a [CarbonCopy](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#carbon-copies-recipient) recipient will also receive an email that an envelope is completed.

---

#### Carbon Copy Recipients

Documentation [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#carbon-copies-recipient)

> Carbon copy recipients get a copy of the envelope but don't need to sign, initial, date or add information to any of the documents. This type of recipient can be used in any routing order. Carbon copy recipients receive their copy of the envelope when the envelope reaches the recipient's order in the process flow and when the envelope is completed.

---

#### Sending Envelope with notifications to CC recipients before and after Signer

Documentation [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#carbon-copies-recipient)

You are getting the `ENVELOPE_HAS_DUPLICATE_RECIPIENTS` error message since you have specified `recipientId = 1` for multiple recipients. Also you can remove the `roleName` as there is no template involved.

Here is an example that should work for your use case. I am using unique routing order and recipient ID for each of the recipients.

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes

{
  "emailSubject": "Envelope with  1 cc - 1 signer - 1 cc",
  "status": "sent",
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "email": "AndySigner@acme.com",
                "name": "Andy Signer",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "routingOrder" : "2",
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [
                        {
                            "documentId": "1","pageNumber": "1", "xPosition": "80", "yPosition": "80",
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "carbonCopies": [
           {
               "name": "Jane CC",
               "email": "Janecc@acme.com",
               "recipientId": "1",
               "routingOrder": "1"
           },
           {
               "name": "Bob CC",
               "email": "BobCC@acme.com",
               "recipientId": "3",
               "routingOrder": "3"
           }           
        ],
    },
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentId": "1",
            "name": "Contract",
            "fileExtension": "txt",
            "documentBase64": "RG9jIFRXTyBUV08gVFdP"
        }
    ]
}
```